# Why theta*X not theta'*X in practical?

Tags: machine-learning, octave

While doing MOOC on ML by Andrew Ng, he in theory explains `theta'*X` gives us hypothesis and while doing coursework we use `theta*X`. Why it's so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *mathematics*, a 'vector' is always defined as a vertically-stacked array, e.g. <sub>[image]</sub>, and signifies a *single* point in a 3-dimensional space.

A 'horizontal' vector, typically signifies an array of observations, e.g. <sub>[image]</sub> is a tuple of 3 *scalar* observations.

Equally, a matrix can be thought of as a collection of vectors. E.g., the following is a collection of four 3-dimensional vectors:
<sub>[image]</sub>

A scalar can be thought of as a matrix of size 1x1, and therefore its transpose is the same as the original.

More generally, an n-by-m matrix `W` can also be thought of as a transformation from an m-dimensional vector `x` to an n-dimensional vector `y`, since multiplying that matrix with an m-dimensional vector will yield a new n-dimensional one. If your 'matrix' `W` is '1xn', then this denotes a transformation from an n-dimensional vector to a scalar.

Therefore, notationally, it is customary to introduce the problem from the mathematical notation point of view, e.g. `y = Wx`.

However, for computational reasons, sometimes it makes more sense to perform the calculation as a "vector times a matrix" rather than "matrix times a vector". Since `(Wx)' === x'W'`, sometimes we solve the problem like that, and treat `x'` as a horizontal vector. Also, if `W` is not a matrix, but a scalar, then `Wx` denotes scalar multiplication, and therefore in this case `Wx === xW`.

I don't know the exercises you speak of, but my assumption would be that in the course he introduced `theta` as a proper, vertical vector, but then transposed it to perform proper calculations, i.e. a transformation from a vector of n-dimensions to a scalar (which is your prediction).

Then in the exercises, presumably you were *either* dealing with a scalar 'theta' so there was no point transposing it, and was left as theta for convenience ***or***, theta was now defined as a horizontal (i.e. transposed) vector to begin with for some reason (e.g. printing convenience), and then was left in that state when performing the necessary transformation.

Comment: didn't you swap the meanings there? as far as i know, a 1x3 horizontal vector is one observation of data, therefore it is a single 3-dimentional / n-dimentional point. and a 3x1 vertical vector would be three separate 1-dimentional points, since it's 3 observations.

Comment: @N.Joppi no; what you mention is the convention in databases & database-like objects (e.g. 'dataframes'): rows correspond to 'records' and columns correspond to 'fields'. This is mostly done for practical reasons (e.g. console output). In maths a vector is traditionally denoted as a vertical arrangement of scalars, where the number of elements denotes the dimensionality of the vector. Matrices build on vectors: one particular (though not the only) interpretation of matrices is as a 'collection' of vectors. A "horizontal vector" can then be thought of as a collection of one-dimensional vectors.

Answer (score 7):

**theta'*X** is used to calculate the hypothesis for a *single training example* *when X is a* **vector**. Then you have to calculate **theta'** to get to the h(x) definition.

In the practice, since you have **more than one training example**, **X is a Matrix** (*your training set*) with "m x n" dimension where *m is the number of your training examples* and *n your number of features*.

Now, you want to calculate h(x) for all your training examples with your theta parameter in just one move right?

Here is the **trick**: *theta has to be a n x 1 vector* then when you do Matrix-Vector Multiplication (X*theta) you will obtain an m x 1 vector with all your h(x)'s training examples in your training set (X matrix). Matrix multiplication will create the vector h(x) row by row making the corresponding math and this will be equal to the h(x) definition at each training example.

You can do the math by hand, I did it and now is clear. Hope i can help someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the dimensions for your `theta` and `X` are (you haven't provided anything) but actually it all depends on the `X`, `theta` and hypothesis dimensions. Let's say `m` is the number of features and `n` - the number of examples. Then, if `theta` is a `mx1` vector and `X` is a `nxm` matrix then `X*theta` is a `nx1` hypothesis vector.

<strike>But you will get the same result if calculate `theta'*X`. You can also get the same result with `theta*X` if `theta` is `1xm` and `X` - `mxn`</strike>

**Edit:**

As @Tasos Papastylianou pointed out the same result will be obtained if `X` is `mxn` then `(theta.'*X).'` or `X.'*theta` are answers. If the hypothesis should be a `1xn` vector then `theta.'*X` is an answer. If `theta` is `1xm`, `X` - `mxn` and the hypothesis is `1xn` then `theta*X` is also a correct answer.

Comment: This is a bit misleading; you're making it sound as if  `X * theta` and `theta.' * X` are equivalent. They're not, not even for square matrices where the calculation is allowed. E.g. `X = [1,2;3,4]; t=[5;6]; disp(t.'*X); disp(X*t);`.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem for me. (ML course, linear regression)
after spending time on it, here is how i see it: there is a confusion between the x(i) vector and the X matrix.

About the hypothesis h(xi) for a xi vector (xi belongs to R3x1), theta belongs to R3x1
        `theta = [to;t1;t2] #R(3x1)
        theta' = [to t1 t2] #R(1x3)
        xi = [1 ; xi1 ; xi2] #(R3x1)
        theta' * xi => to + t1.xi,1 +t2.xi,2`

## = h(xi)  (which is a R1x1 => a real number)

to the theta'*xi works here

About the vectorization equation
in this case X is not the same thing as x (vector). it is a matrix with m rows and n+1 col (m =number of examples and n number of features on which we add the to term)

therefore from the previous example with n= 2, 
the matrix X is a m x 3 matrix
    X = [1 xo,1 xo,2 ; 1 x1,1 x1,2 ; .... ; 1 xi,1  xi,2 ; ...; 1 xm,1 xm,2]

if you want to vectorize the equation for the algorithm, you need to consider for that for each row i, you will have the h(xi) (a real number)
so you need to implement  X * theta

that will give you for each row i 
    `[ 1 xi,1 xi,2] * [to ; t1 ; t2] = to + t1.xi,1 + t2.xi,2`

Hope it helps

Comment: and sorry for how it is written

Answer (score 2):

I have used octave notation and syntax for writing matrices: 'comma' for separating column items, 'semicolon' for separating row items and 'single quote' for Transpose.

In the **course theory** under discussion, `theta =` [theta<sub>0</sub>; theta<sub>1</sub>;   theta<sub>2</sub>;   theta<sub>3</sub>; .... theta<sub>f</sub>].

'theta' is therefore a column vector or '(f+1) x 1' matrix. Here 'f' is the number of features. theta<sub>0</sub> is the intercept term.

With just one training example, x is a '(f+1) x 1' matrix or a column vector.  Specifically `x =` [x<sub>0</sub>; x<sub>1</sub>; x<sub>2</sub>; x<sub>3</sub>; .... x<sub>f</sub>]
x<sub>0</sub> is always '1'.

In this special case the '1 x (f+1)' matrix formed by taking theta**'** and x could be multiplied to give the correct '1x1' hypothesis matrix or a real number.

`h = theta' * x` is a valid expression.

But the  **coursework**  deals with multiple training examples. If there are 'm' training examples, **X** is a 'm x (f+1)' matrix.

To simplify, let there be two training examples each with 'f' features.

**X** = [ x<sup>1</sup>; x<sup>2</sup>].

(Please note 1 and 2 inside the brackets are not exponential terms but indexes for the training examples).

Here, x<sup>1</sup> = [ x<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup>, x<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup>, x<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup>, x<sub>3</sub><sup>1</sup>, .... x<sub>f</sub><sup>1</sup> ]
and
x<sup>2</sup> = [ x<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>, x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>, x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup>, .... x<sub>f</sub><sup>2</sup>].

So X is a '2 x (f+1)' matrix.

Now to answer the question, theta**'** is a '1 x (f+1)' matrix and X is a '2 x (f+1)' matrix. With this, the following expressions are not valid.

1. `theta' * X`
2. `theta * X`

The expected hypothesis matrix, '**h**', should have two predicted values (two real numbers), one for each of the two training examples. '**h**' is a '2 x 1' matrix or column vector.

The hypothesis can be obtained only by using the expression, `X * theta` which is valid and algebraically correct. Multiplying a '2 x (f+1)' matrix with a '(f+1) x 1' matrix resulting in a '2 x 1' hypothesis matrix.

Answer (score 2):

When Andrew Ng first introduced x in the cost function J(theta), x is a **column vector**
aka

```
[x0; x1; ... ; xn]

i.e. 

x0;
x1;
...;
xn
```

However, in the first programming assignment, we are given X, which is an (m * n) matrix, (# training examples * features per training example). The discrepancy comes with the fact that from file the individual x vectors(training samples) are stored as horizontal row vectors rather than the vertical column vectors!!

This means the X matrix you see is actually an X' (X Transpose) matrix!!

Since we have X', we need to make our code work given our equation is looking for h(theta) = theta' * X(when the vectors in matrix X are column vectors)

we have the linear algebra identity for matrix and vector multiplication:

**(A*B)' == (B') * (A')** as shown here [Properties of Transposes](https://www.web-formulas.com/Math_Formulas/Linear_Algebra_Properties_of_Transposes.aspx)

```
let t = theta,
given, h(t) = t' * X
h(t)' = (t' X)'
= X' * t
```

Now we have our variables in the format they were actually given to us. What I mean is that our input file really holds X' and theta is normal, so multiplying them in the order specified above will give a practically equivilant output to that he taught us to use which was theta' * X. Since we are summing all the elements of h(t)' at the end it doesn't matter that it is transposed for the final calculation. However, if you wanted h(t), not h(t)', you could always take your computed result and transpose it because

```
(A')' == A
```

However, for the coursera machine learning programming assignment 1, this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the computer has the coordinate (0,0) positioned on the top left, while geometry has the coordinate (0,0) positioned on the bottom left.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp3D3.png)