# linear regression with one variable Gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

I want to ask how this equation

[image: gradient descent equation]

can be written at octave by this way

```
predictions = X * theta;
delta = (1/m) * X' * (predictions - y);
theta = theta - alpha * delta;
```

I dont understand from where transpose come and how this equation converted to ve by this way?

Comment: This question has been asked a few times, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51753240/4183191

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why theta\*X not theta'\*X in practical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753240/why-thetax-not-thetax-in-practical)

Comment: I already read this and understood why theta' * X = X * theta , but i don't understand here why (h(x) - y(x))*x  converted to  X' * (predictions - y)

Answer (score 0):

The scalar product `X.Y` is mathematically `sum (xi * yi)` and can be written as `X' * Y` in octave when `X` and `Y` are vectors.

There are other ways to write a scalar product in octave, cf
https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/dot.html

Comment: well, yes and no. It can be written this way *for this particular set of matrices*. When you do `X'*Y` in octave it does not necessarily mean you want to perform a scalar product. IT could be just some matrix mult.

Comment: Of course my answer has to be read from the context of the question where X and Y are vectors

Comment: you mean xj converted to X' ?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be, given an example where:

```
X     = randn(m, k);   % m 'input' horizontal-vectors of dimensionality k
y     = randn(m, n);   % m 'target' horizontal-vectors of dimensionality n

theta = randn(k, n);   % a (right) transformation from k to n dimensional
                       % horizontal-vectors

h     = X * theta;     % creates m rows of n-dimensional horizontal vectors
```

how is it that the following code

```
delta = zeros(k,n)
for j = 1 : k           % iterating over all dimensions of the input
    for l = 1 : n       % iterating over all dimensions of the output

        for i = 1 : m   % iterating over all observations for that j,l pair
            delta(j, l) += (1/m) * (h(i, l) - y(i, l)) * x(i,j);
        end

        theta(j, l) = theta(j, l) - alpha * delta(j, l);

    end
end
```

can be vectorised as:

```
  h      = X * theta ;
  delta  = (1/ m) * X' * (h - y);
  theta  = theta - alpha * delta;
```

To confirm such a vectorised formulation makes sense, it always helps to note (e.g. below each line) the dimensions of the objects involved in the matrix / vectorised operations:

```
  h      = X      * theta ;
% [m, n]   [m, k]   [k, n]

  delta  = (1/ m) * X'     * (h - y);
% [k, n]   [1, 1]   [k, m]   [m, n]

  theta  = theta - alpha  * delta; 
% [k, n]   [k,n]   [1, 1]   [k, n]
```

Hopefully now it will become more obvious that they are equivalent.

W.r.t the `X' * D` calculation (where `D = predictions - y`) you can see that:
performing matrix multiplication with the 1st row of `X'` and the 1st column of D is equal to summing for `k=1` and `n=1` over all *m* observations, and placing that result at position [k=1, n=1] in the resulting matrix output. Then moving along the columns of D and still multiplying by the 1st row of `X'`, you can see that we are simply moving along the n dimensions in D, and placing the result accordingly in the output. Similarly, moving along the rows of `X'`, you move along the k dimensions of `X'`, performing the same process for all n in that D, and placing the results accordingly, until you've finished matrix multiplications over all rows of X and columns in D.

If you follow the logic above, you will see that the summations involved are exactly the same as in the for loop formulation, but we managed to avoid using a for loop and use matrix operations instead.